# MyISAM tables not found in event log AWS RDS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, innodb, myisam

We noticed that in our MySQL RDS the following message appeared in the event log:

DB Instance contains MyISAM tables that have not been migrated to InnoDB. These tables can impact your ability to perform point-in-time restores. Consider converting these tables to InnoDB.

Being that, we checked all the schemas and found no table in MyISAM.

How to convert a table that we didn't find?

What could be happening?

Is there any way to check if there is a hidden table?

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to detect, if there are any MyISAM tables

```
SELECT
    table_schema AS DATABSE_NAME,
    table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables 
WHERE
     engine = 'MyISAM'
     and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
     and table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'sys',
                               'performance_schema','mysql')
ORDER BY 
   table_schema, table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we ran your query and did not show any MyISAM tables, we have also disconnected, connected and updated the recommended MySQL version of RDS, but the AWS message still appears in the event log.

Comment: as you can see i excluded sytsm tables and mysql and so on, when you get no repsonse frpm that query, the MyISAM tables are in that schemas, which you can not convert see for exqample here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197879/aws-rds-myisam-tables-from-mysql-and-information-schema-and-good-snapshots so you have to ignore it